# Instantiating Image picker from a custom table cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimagepickercontroller, modalviewcontroller

In my app, I have a table view controller that creates a couple of customize cells, which I have created view controllers (.xib) and classes for. In one of those cells, there is a button that triggers a method (at 'touch up inside') that is suppose to present the user with an image picker. I have used apple standard code from the documentation for presenting the media picker, but it doesn't seem to work. I have tried using the cell as both the delegate and view controller which the media picker is created from, and as the delegate for the media picker, but it doesn't seem to work. I have also tried Insiniciating an object of the UITableView the cell is created in, and using it as the delegate and view controller, which also doesn't work. I have added the code for the related methods. Any advice on how to do that?

The method to handle buttons 'touch up inside" (method his in the custom cell class):

```
- (IBAction)TakeNewPicture:(id)sender {
    [self startCameraControllerFromViewController:self usingDelegate:self];
}
```

The startCameraController... method (also in the cell's class):

```
- (BOOL) startCameraControllerFromViewController: (UIViewController*) controller
                                   usingDelegate: (id <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
                                                   UINavigationControllerDelegate>) delegate {

    if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
          UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == NO)
        || (delegate == nil)
        || (controller == nil))
        return NO;


    UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    // Displays a control that allows the user to choose picture or
    // movie capture, if both are available:
    cameraUI.mediaTypes =
    [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:
     UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];

    // Hides the controls for moving & scaling pictures, or for
    // trimming movies. To instead show the controls, use YES.
    cameraUI.allowsEditing = YES;

    cameraUI.delegate = delegate;

   [controller presentModalViewController: cameraUI animated: YES];
    //[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] presentModalViewController:cameraUI animated:YES];
    return YES;
}
```

Thanks for your time! Any support is highly appreciated :] (Objective-c style smiley)

Comment: Do you know if execution is actually getting to that `presentModalViewController` line? Or if it is actually getting into `startCameraControllerFromViewController`? You might want to place some NSLog statements so you can tell. You could also use NSLog to ensure that the cameraUI Object is not null when it after being initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I hope u r not running this in the simulator, because as u know it doesn't have a camera:)

You say that `TakeNewPicture` is in the custom cell class, and inside it you call `[self startCameraControllerFromViewController:self usingDelegate:self];`
Were self is a custom cell not a UIViewController..

I would suggest to move this code to the viewController and when u create a cell just do

```
[[cell button] addTarget:self action:@selector(TakeNewPicture:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Well I have created the method 'startCameraControllerFromView...' in the TableView class where the cell is instantiated, and called it from the cell (instantiated a new TableView and called the method, with the table view being both view controller and delegate (code looks like that: EditProfileTableViewController * TableView = [[EditProfileTableViewController alloc] init];
    [TableView startCameraControllerFromViewController:TableView usingDelegate:TableView];       )    Now it starts the function startCameraFromViewController..., (I have checked with an NSLog), {continue on next reply}

Comment: But it doesn't actually work. I am using simulator, so can that be the problem? if so, do you think it will eventually work? (in theory, of course)...

Comment: U don't have a camera in the simulator so of course it is a problem, in your startCameraControllerFromViewController method u check if the device support a camera with [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
          UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == NO, and this cause the method to call return;

Comment: cheers thanks for your awesome support. I guess ill just have to spend 99$ as registering as an apple developer and testing on my iPhone... had to know this day will eventually come.

Comment: Lol u can't avoid it.. the simulator is a great tool but no one can develop a decent app without testing it on real device... Glad I could help, answer accept will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this cannot work because a `UITableViewCell` or `UITableView` is not a `UIViewController` object, which you need to call `presentModalViewController:animated:`. I think the best solution is to let your view controller handle all the touch events on the cells' buttons.

So you should put the `takeNewPicture:` (methods should start with a small letter) action method inside your view controller class and assign the view controller as the button's target. Inside the action method, you then need to use the `sender` argument to identify the cell which the user tapped on. The best way to do this is to assign a `tag` to each button that is equal to that cell's row index inside the table view. You can then use `[sender tag]` to identify the index path of the cell that contains the button that was tapped.